# Does the tf.data.Dataset support to generate dictionary structure?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

The following is a piece of code from [https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets]. In this example, the `map` function is a user-defined function to read the data. And in the `map` function, we need to set the output types are `[tf.uint8, label.dtype]`.

```
import cv2

# Use a custom OpenCV function to read the image, instead of the standard
# TensorFlow `tf.read_file()` operation.
def _read_py_function(filename, label):
  image_decoded = cv2.imread(image_string, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  return image_decoded, label

# Use standard TensorFlow operations to resize the image to a fixed shape.
def _resize_function(image_decoded, label):
  image_decoded.set_shape([None, None, None])
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [28, 28])
  return image_resized, label

  filenames = ["/var/data/image1.jpg", "/var/data/image2.jpg", ...]
  labels = [0, 37, 29, 1, ...]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(
  lambda filename, label: tuple(tf.py_func(
    _read_py_function, [filename, label], [tf.uint8, label.dtype])))
dataset = dataset.map(_resize_function)
```

My question is, if we want to the `_read_py_function()` output a Python dictionary, then how do we set the outptu types? Is there an inherit data type such as `tf.dict`? For example:

```
def _read_py_function(filename):
  image_filename = filename[0]
  label_filename = filename[1]
  image_id = filename[2]
  image_age = filename[3]
  image_decoded = cv2.imread(image_filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  image_decoded = cv2.imread(label_fielname, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  return {'image':image_decoded, 'label':label_decoded, 'id':image_id, 'age':image_age}
```

Then, how do we design the `dataset.map()` function?

Comment: What TensorFlow version are you using? I believe TensorFlow 1.4 does support dicts, while 1.2 does not (but does support tuples).

Comment: Hi @de1, thanks for comment! I'm using 1.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Returning dicts inside the function called by `tf.data.Dataset.map` should work as expected.

Here is an example:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: {'a': x, 'b': 2 * x})
dataset = dataset.map(lambda y: y['a'] + y['b'])

res = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(10):
        assert sess.run(res) == 3 * i
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Moindrot, Thank you! Currently I'm still first converting the data into TFRecords, and serialized the data(image +text) into the TFRecords. In the future when I would try your method, then I'll give feedback. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answer this also works:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: {'a': x, 'b': 2 * x})

res = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(10):
        curr_res = sess.run(res)
        assert curr_res['a'] == i
        assert curr_res['b'] == 2 * i
```